# Browser address bar not showing full url

Tags: php, jquery

I use this code to open the contents of my Menu Links inside my Main div so I do not need to refresh the whole page each time:

```
.delegate('a.difflink', 'click', function(){
         $('#content').empty();
         var page = $(this).attr('id');
         $('#content').load("page_scripts/loop_a.php?page="+ page);
```

Problem created is that by using the above code my browser's address bar always shows **www.myXample.com**

And as I understand (not sure if I am correct) the way I made it work is like there are no new urls to show (since I am just changing div content).

Is there a way to change my url to match my content (e.g if I press Downloads I get **www.myXample.com/downloads**) and still no need to refresh the whole page?

Comment: You must use URL Rewriting for modifying the url by javascript in APACHE there is `.htaccess` method.. so finally u want to modify your url without page refresh rite??? and Use `#` Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.delegate('a.difflink', 'click', function(){
         $('#content').empty();
         var page = $(this).attr('id');
         $('#content').load("page_scripts/loop_a.php?page="+ page);
         window.history.pushState('','','/page1');
   });
```

This will change the URL in the address bar to www.myexample.com/page1

Comment: The above addition does (partialy atm) the trick but will it count for SEO?